# browser specific css rendering issues

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer

Chrome
[image]

IE Standard mode
[image]

if you compare both the pages the `IE standard mode` is having little bit larger font-weight as compared to the `Google chorme`.

[Open this page in both chrome and IE standard mode](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_font-face_rule)

exactly what i am saying is open whatever page you want to ,and compare it in chrome and IE standard mode  . The IE standard mode  is taking little bit larger css font-weight than chrome

how solve this isssue.,when i want my web page font  to be  neutral.. means it should take the same font which i have given in css

please give me the solution, thanks in advance

Comment: What version of IE?

Comment: version :- 11.248.16299.0

Comment: 1. you are using a 3rd party web site that may or may not affect the final output. 2. you do not specify the font-size so the browser will render at it's default size. 3. the page zoom levels might be different.

Comment: @jeff https://jsfiddle.net/vzvuxytt/5/  click this link for refernce

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue, this is just behavior of each browser how it behave in its different way, why because all browsers are not made of same development(Chrome, IE, FireFox).

**Solution:** Use reset CSS to avoid difference between browser rendering.

https://www.webpagefx.com/blog/web-design/css-tip-1-resetting-your-styles-with-css-reset/

Comment: i have referred to your link.... and created this page ->>>>https://jsfiddle.net/vzvuxytt/19/ open this page in both IE and Chrome.. the issue still exits..

Answer (score 0):

I tried to compare it on IE11 and chrome but it looks okay on my end but if its really a bother, you can use some css hacks for IE and adjust the font size and font weight.

IE10 and IE11

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
    .selector { property:value; }
}
```